# Coverage probability for an unspecified CDF

Tags: r, resampling, confidence-interval, binomial-cdf

I used the following `r` code to determine the coverage probability.

```
theta <- seq(0,1, length = 100)
CD_theta <- function(y, p, n){
  1 - pbinom (y, size = n, prob = p) + 1/2*dbinom(y, size = n, prob = p)
}

y <- 5
n <- 100
phat <- y/n
mytheta <- CD_theta(5, theta, 100)

set.seed(650)
ci <- list()
n <- 100
B <- 1000
result = rep(NA, B)
all_confInt <- function(B) {
for (i in 1:B){
  boot.sample <- sample(mytheta, replace = TRUE)
  lower <- theta[which.min(abs(boot.sample - .025))]
  upper <- theta[which.min(abs(boot.sample - .975))]
  ci[[i]] <- data.frame(lowerCI = lower, upperCI = upper)
  intervals <- unlist(ci)
}
  return(intervals)
}

df <- data.frame(matrix(all_confInt(B), nrow=B, byrow=T))
colnames(df)[1] <- "Lower"
colnames(df)[2] <- "Upper"
names(df)
dim(df)
mean(df$Lower < phat & df$Upper > phat)*100
```

However, I obtained 6.4% which is too low. Why am I getting really lower percentage?. Is there any problem in the `r` function?

Comment: Why do you have `intervals <- unlist(ci)` inside the loop instead of outside?

Comment: I used `intervals <- ci` and then the data frame I used `df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(all_confInt(B)), nrow=B, byrow=T))`, but still I got the same 6.4%.

Comment: Well, the point is that the code is just very inefficient and could be much simpler for doing the same thing.  e.g. `all_confInt <- function(B, mytheta) {
  Upper <- numeric()
  Lower <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:B){
    boot.sample <- sample(mytheta, replace = TRUE)
    Lower[i] <- theta[which.min(abs(boot.sample - .025))]
    Upper[i] <- theta[which.min(abs(boot.sample - .975))]
    
  }

  return(data.frame("lower" = Lower, "upper" = Upper))
}

df_so <- all_confInt(B, mytheta)`  .  But you still are not being clear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think your question is more about understanding the statistics.  There is a programming question there but it's not what you are focused on.   However if you take a look at `mytheta` you'll see that what you are doing does not give you something close to normal.

Comment: @Elin Thank you. But still it produces the same value.

Comment: @ Elin I understood the mistake I am making. I need to find the total number of counts of `(df_so$lower <phat <df_so$upper)`